# R Looping and mutate

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am new to R. I have a column that have remarks -"positive". "negative" and others.

I wanted to create a new column called "ranges". In this column I want to write remarks based on positive/negative etc. If `remarks =="positive"` i want to write to corresponding cell "1st lap", if negative "2nd lap".  dataset =balls. I am writing the following:

```
library(dplyr)
balls %>%
    mutate(ranges) %>%
    for (i in balls$sentiment) {
        if (i=="positive"){
            balls$ranges = "1st lap"
        } else if (i=="negative") {
            balls$ranges = "2nd lap"
        } else {
            balls$ranges = ""
        }
    }
```

But it's not doing job. How to write this please.... is there any offset function like we have in Excel VBA to use in for loop? regards,

Comment: Hi Syed, in general, please explain the error you get. Here, you don't want to try to use a `for` loop inside a dplyr pipe. Keep those things separate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ifelse in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252288/using-ifelse-in-r)

Comment: Sorry for that. The problem I am getting is- in the new column that I have created with mutate, I get the result based on the last value. For example- if the last value was positive, all the cells in the Range column become "1st lap". - hope this make sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution based on case_when:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:6, sentiment= c("positive", "negative", "other", "positive", "bb", "positive"))
df$ranges <- case_when(
  df$sentiment == "positive" ~"1st lap",
  df$sentiment == "negative" ~"2nd lap",
  TRUE ~ ""
)
```

Comment: this one looks promising to me. I will have a go at this tonight and let you know. I never seen case_when before. Thanks for the tip...

Answer (score 2):

Just expanding on the comments, I think this might be what you're after?

```
mutate(ranges=ifelse(sentiment=="positive","1st lap", ifelse(sentiment=="negative","2nd lap","")))
```